# Get query result of multiple row in single row?

Tags: mysql

I have one table with product details in each row where each item is unique.Second table is tax basis which have multiple tax for any single item. I want result which should have single row for each item and all tax related to that item should be in that row with other details

```
item
item_id name type
1. bike vehicle

tax
id tax_name  tax_rate item_id
1. tax1       12        1
2. tax2       13        1
3. tax3       14        1
```

Result should be:

```
id name type tax_name_1 tax_rate_1 tax_name_2 tax_rate_2 tax_name_3 tax_rate_3
1  bike vehicle tax1        12        tax2      13          tax3         14
```

Comment: please give the schema of tax table.

Comment: To know the column in tax table which corresponds to item

Comment: item id is related to both table

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical table pivot issue, try this:

```
select
    item.*,
    max(case when tax.id = 1 then tax_name end) as tax_name_1,
    max(case when tax.id = 1 then tax_rate end) as tax_rate_1,
    max(case when tax.id = 2 then tax_name end) as tax_name_2,
    max(case when tax.id = 2 then tax_rate end) as tax_rate_2,
    max(case when tax.id = 3 then tax_name end) as tax_name_3,
    max(case when tax.id = 3 then tax_rate end) as tax_rate_3
from item
join tax
group by item.id
```

Comment: number of taxes is not fixed

Comment: @AshishSinghal If it's dynamic, here you must use dynamic sql to do it. And please add this information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think simple inner join will do this task for you

```
SELECT item.*, tax.taxname,tax.taxrate
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN tax
    ON item.id=tax.id;
```